# xcodebuild fails with "Cannot determine the current working directory" if I use it in a loop

Tags: bash, xcodebuild

I'm building a small script to run xcodebuild with different settings.
That's why I'm using a loop to iterate my device settings.

Everything works fine as long as I have only one item in my list. If I have two, the first build runs successful but the second, third, etc will fail with the error `Cannot determine the current working directory`.

That is very confusing. Thanks for your help.

**Update**

My shorted script:

```
for DEVICE in ${DEVICE_LIST[*]}
do
    # DEVICE => 'iPhone 5' or 'iPhone 6'
    # SCHEME_NAME => 'myXcodeSchemeName'
    xcodebuild test -scheme $SCHEME_NAME -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=${IDENTIFIER},OS=9.1" -resultBundlePath $OUTPUT_WORKING_DIR
done
```

If something is missing, I'll add it.

Comment: Post your script. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @4ae1e1 I added the iteration part of my script as an update to the original post. If do you need more source, I'll append it.